# ":term" style completion in vim.ui.input()

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, lua

I currently have the following keymap:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>sr', function() return ":vs | term " end, { expr = true })
```

This drops me into a vim command where I can complete the invocation of `term` by typing in the terminal command I'd like to run. The nice thing about this is that I get all kinds of nice completions while I'm finishing the command invocation. Shell commands will tab-complete as well as file paths, and I'm sure other things.

I'd like to something that's more "pure lua" while also utilizing `vim.ui.input`. I've developed the following:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>sr', function()
    vim.ui.input({
        prompt = 'Run shell command: ',
        completion = 'shellcmd',
    }, function(command)
        if command ~= nil and command ~= "" then
            vim.cmd.split()
            vim.cmd.term(command)
        else
            vim.notify("command aborted")
        end
    end)
end)
```

This mostly works, however the completion isn't as good. Only the names of shell commands will auto complete, file paths and other entities that would complete if I were just doing `:term` don't seem to want to complete.

Is there a way I can get better completion here? Even just being able to do `shellcmd` and `file` completion would be great.